# uploading to google drive with paperclip in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip, google-drive-api

Hello there i am new to using the [google drive](http://rubygems.org/gems/google_drive) gem and i do not know how to use it with paperclip to upload photos to the [google drive](http://rubygems.org/gems/google_drive). Its a simple rails application that i am developing that uploads photos to [google drive](http://rubygems.org/gems/google_drive), is there any rails application example that i can use to get me started with the gem or can any body present an example here to aid we beginners using the [google drive gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/google_drive). Paperclip should be used to upload the files. Thank You

Comment: This question does not deserve to be voted down. Pls y is it voted down

Comment: Check out the first eight words of the title attribute on the down-vote arrow: http://d4static.com/c/skitched-20120726-211402.png That is why I down-voted the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd likely have to implement a storage adapter for Paperclip. Take a look at something like https://github.com/dripster82/paperclipdropbox as an example. In that case, it looks like it only supports uploading to a single pre-authorized account. If that's OK, then modifying that to talk to Google Drive instead of Dropbox should be straightforward. If you need to support multiple users, you'd have to make sure the right credentials are being used for the current user.

Anyway, the paperclip docs are likely the best place to get started :)

Comment: I would recommend using fog as your storage adapter.  It is supported by paperclip and supports google storage.
http://fog.io/1.4.0/storage/

Comment: Google Storage for Developers != Google Drive. The former is more akin to S3 and designed to be managed by apps/developers. Drive is designed for users to own & manage their files and delegate access to apps. Paperclip seems more designed for the former case though.

Comment: Based on Uchenna's use case, Google Storage is a better fit than Google Drive as Uchenna is using it for an application storage and not personal storage.

Comment: I am greatful for this answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: From you answer, I have to create a new gem and call it paperclipgoogledrive and instead of requiring dropbox, I should require the googledrive gem